# Unable to execute shell script via java servlet

Tags: java, shell, servlets, processbuilder

I'm trying to execute a simple shell script via java servlet using process builder and I'm not getting any output. I searched for number of solution on stack overflow but nothing helped me out yet...
Here is my code that I'm trying to execute..

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="SmxServlet">
    <input type="submit" value="Click">
</form>
```

Shell script:

```
echo Hello world!, here your args $@ > log.html 2>&1
```

SmxServlet.java:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        String[] command = {"/bin/bash", "test.sh", "Argument1"};
        ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        Process p2 = p.start();
        try {
            p2.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p2.getInputStream()));
        String line;

        System.out.println("Output of running " + command + " is: ");
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        //RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("log.html");
        //dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
```

As out put in console, I'm getting below with no value:

```
Output of running [Ljava.lang.String;@77f03096 is:
```

Can anyone out there please help with this? Is there anything that I'm doing wrong?How to fix it? Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Your command doesn't generate any output on the standard output, so Java doesn't receive any. That's because your echo command sends everything to the file `log.html` rather than the standard output stream.

Comment: Did you try with "echo Hello world!" only,to see if it is working?

Comment: What other errors did you get?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt No, the output is not getting copied to log.html as well.

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal yes I tried only "echo Hello world!" as well but still stuck... I'm not getting any errors.. its just the code is not working.. I'm using eclipse and tomcat 7, in case if they are culprits.

Answer (score 0):

Your command doesn't generate any output on the standard output, so Java doesn't receive any. That's because your echo command sends everything to the file `log.html` rather than the standard output stream.

However, there is another problem: the exclamation mark has a special meaning in the shell. If you run your script manually, you'll see an error like `bash: !,: event not found`

So you need to escape the exclamation mark.

Change the command in `test.sh` to

```
echo Hello world\!, here your args $@
```

to make it work

Comment: Actually nothing is printing in log.html as well and per your suggestion I did made the changes and it still doesn't work. running the test.sh script manually is not giving me any error.